# Can you bake meshes with overlapping UV faces?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

So I've got an object that looks like this: 
[image]
And, since I used the *Decimate* modifier, the UV map looks like this:

[image]

Can this be baked? or will everything just mess up?

Comment: It *can* be baked but it will yield weird and most likely undesirable results without a proper unwrap and non-overlapping texture coordinates.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Can this be corrected with a simple Smart UV project or will there be problems?

Comment: It probably could, but whichever method you choose you still have to manually make sure there are no overlapping parts. If you are trying to avoid the hassle or manual work you can try the *Light Map Pack* option at the expense of continuity.